# What do PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH vars need to be set to for s3cmd on Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I just installed s3cmd via homebrew on Mac High Sierra.  Immediately when I go to run it, I get this error ...

```
davea$ s3cmd
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
  PYTHONPATH = '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin'
  program name = '/usr/local/Cellar/s3cmd/2.0.2_2/libexec/bin/python3.8'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/local/Cellar/s3cmd/2.0.2_2/libexec/bin/python3.8'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
  sys.executable = '/usr/local/Cellar/s3cmd/2.0.2_2/libexec/bin/python3.8'
  sys.prefix = '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fff9f066380 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

I have verified that my $PYTHONHOME and $PYTHONPATH paths actually exist but am unclear what the errors mean.  I have also tried reinstalling Python via homebrew.

What do I need to set PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH env vars to get this to work?

Comment: It looks like you have two different Python versions installed, 3.7 and 3.8 and there's some conflict. You probably should figure out why there are two versions stomping on one another.

Comment: Side-note: These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd` (which hasn't been updated in years).